# SqlCommand.Prepare method requires all parameters to have an explicitly type set

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I would like to use a prepared statement to insert some data into a SQL Server database.

The query I would like is:

```
INSERT INTO salesdata([OriginalFilename], [InterchangeReceiverID], [Distributor],
       [DE_Date], [DE_VendorNR], [DE_VendorDEANR], [DE_VendorName],
       [DE_DistributionCenterNR], [DE_DistributionCenterID],
       [DE_DistributionCenterName], [DE_ItemNR],[DE_ItemNDCNR], [DE_ProductUOM],
       [DE_CustomerAccountNR], [DE_CustomerDEANR], [DE_CustomerNPINR],
       [DE_CustomerHINNR], [DE_CustomerName], [DE_CustomerAddress1],
       [DE_CustomerAddress2], [DE_CustomerCity], [DE_CustomerState],
       [DE_CustomerZipcode], [DE_CustomerCountry], [DE_InvoiceNR], [DE_Invoicedate],
       [DE_QuantitySold], [DE_QuantityReturned], [DE_SalesReturnCode],
       [DE_ContractNR], [DE_Price])
VALUES(@OriginalFilename, @InterchangeReceiverID, @Distributor,
       @DE_Date, @DE_VendorNR, @DE_VendorDEANR, @DE_VendorName,
       @DE_DistributionCenterNR, @DE_DistributionCenterID,
       @DE_DistributionCenterName, @DE_ItemNR, @DE_ItemNDCNR, @DE_ProductUOM,
       @DE_CustomerAccountNR, @DE_CustomerDEANR, @DE_CustomerNPINR,
       @DE_CustomerHINNR, @DE_CustomerName, @DE_CustomerAddress1,
       @DE_CustomerAddress2, @DE_CustomerCity, @DE_CustomerState,
       @DE_CustomerZipcode, @DE_CustomerCountry, @DE_InvoiceNR, @DE_Invoicedate,
       @DE_QuantitySold, @DE_QuantityReturned, @DE_SalesReturnCode,
       @DE_ContractNR, @DE_Price)
```

I loop over all the parameters like this:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@InterchangeReceiverID", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500));
command.Parameters["@InterchangeReceiverID"].Value = "VALUEGOESHERE";
```

I also tried the `Parameters.Add(name,value)` method, but that's deprecated.

The error I keep getting is:

> *System.InvalidOperationException: SqlCommand.Prepare method requires all parameters to have an explicitly set type.*

Unfortunately he's not mentioning which parameter is causing the problem. I'm using NVarchar's with a size of 500 and decimals with a size of 18 and a scale of 6.

What am I doing wrong, or how can I figure out which parameter is causing the problem? I write all the parameters to a file (with size/scale and values) and all of them look ok...

Full code:

```
SqlCommand command = GetNewSQLCommand(SALESDATAQRY);
        //command.CommandText = SALESDATAQRY;
        logger.Info(command.CommandText);
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@InterchangeReceiverID", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500));
        command.Parameters["@InterchangeReceiverID"].Value = obj.INTERCHANGE.INTERCHANGE_HEADER.INTERCHANGE_RECEIVER_ID;

        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_VendorNR", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500)) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_VendorNR"].Value= obj.INTERCHANGE.INTERCHANGE_HEADER.INTERCHANGE_RECEIVER_ID;

        foreach (PRODUCT_TRANSFER_AND_RESALE_REPORTINTERCHANGEFUNCTIONAL_GROUP funcGroup in obj.INTERCHANGE.FUNCTIONAL_GROUP)
        {                
            if (command.Parameters.Contains("@OriginalFilename")) command.Parameters.Remove("@OriginalFilename");

            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@OriginalFilename", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500)) ;
        command.Parameters["@OriginalFilename"].Value = filename;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Distributor", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500)) ;
        command.Parameters["@Distributor"].Value = "-";
            foreach (PRODUCT_TRANSFER_AND_RESALE_REPORTINTERCHANGEFUNCTIONAL_GROUPTRANSACTIONNAME_INFO ni in funcGroup.TRANSACTION.NAME_INFO){

                if (command.Parameters.Contains("@DE_DistributionCenterNR")) command.Parameters.Remove("@DE_DistributionCenterNR");
                if (command.Parameters.Contains("@DE_DistributionCenterID")) command.Parameters.Remove("@DE_DistributionCenterID");
                if (command.Parameters.Contains("@DE_DistributionCenterName")) command.Parameters.Remove("@DE_DistributionCenterName");

                if (ni.IDENTIFICATION_CODE_QUALIFIER.Equals("ZZ"))
                {
                    if (command.Parameters.Contains("@Distributor")) command.Parameters.Remove("@Distributor");
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Distributor", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500)) ;
        command.Parameters["@Distributor"].Value = ni.IDENTIFICATION_CODE;
                }

                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_DistributionCenterNR", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500)) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_DistributionCenterNR"].Value = ni.IDENTIFICATION_CODE;
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_DistributionCenterID", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500)) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_DistributionCenterID"].Value = ni.IDENTIFICATION_CODE;//identifier code intern 
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_DistributionCenterName", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500)) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_DistributionCenterName"].Value = ni.NAME;//iodentifeirname

            }

            foreach (DTM dtm in funcGroup.TRANSACTION.DTM){
                if (dtm.DATE_QUALIFIER.Equals("090")) {
                    if (command.Parameters.Contains("@DE_Date")) command.Parameters.Remove("@DE_Date");
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_Date", SqlDbType.DateTime )) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_Date"].Value=dtm.DATE; //090 start, 091 end
                }
            }

            if (command.Parameters.Contains("@DE_VendorDEANR")) command.Parameters.Remove("@DE_VendorDEANR");
            if (command.Parameters.Contains("@DE_VendorName")) command.Parameters.Remove("@DE_VendorName");


            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_VendorDEANR", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500)) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_VendorDEANR"].Value = "-";
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_VendorName", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500)) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_VendorName"].Value = "-";
            foreach (PRODUCT_TRANSFER_AND_RESALE_REPORTINTERCHANGEFUNCTIONAL_GROUPTRANSACTIONPTD ptd in funcGroup.TRANSACTION.PTD){                
                if (command.Parameters.Contains("@DE_ItemNR")) command.Parameters.Remove("@DE_ItemNR");
                if (command.Parameters.Contains("@DE_ItemNDCNR")) command.Parameters.Remove("@DE_ItemNDCNR");
                if (command.Parameters.Contains("@DE_ProductUOM")) command.Parameters.Remove("@DE_ProductUOM");
                if (command.Parameters.Contains("@DE_CustomerAccountNR")) command.Parameters.Remove("@DE_CustomerAccountNR");
                if (command.Parameters.Contains("@DE_CustomerDEANR")) command.Parameters.Remove("@DE_CustomerDEANR");
                if (command.Parameters.Contains("@DE_CustomerNPINR")) command.Parameters.Remove("@DE_CustomerNPINR");
                if (command.Parameters.Contains("@DE_CustomerHINNR")) command.Parameters.Remove("@DE_CustomerHINNR");
                if (command.Parameters.Contains("@DE_CustomerName")) command.Parameters.Remove("@DE_CustomerName");
                if (command.Parameters.Contains("@DE_CustomerCity")) command.Parameters.Remove("@DE_CustomerCity");
                if (command.Parameters.Contains("@DE_CustomerState")) command.Parameters.Remove("@DE_CustomerState");
                if (command.Parameters.Contains("@DE_CustomerZipcode")) command.Parameters.Remove("@DE_CustomerZipcode");
                if (command.Parameters.Contains("@DE_CustomerCountry")) command.Parameters.Remove("@DE_CustomerCountry");
                if (command.Parameters.Contains("@DE_QuantitySold")) command.Parameters.Remove("@DE_QuantitySold");
                if (command.Parameters.Contains("@DE_QuantityReturned")) command.Parameters.Remove("@DE_QuantityReturned");
                if (command.Parameters.Contains("@DE_SalesReturnCode")) command.Parameters.Remove("@DE_SalesReturnCode");
                if (command.Parameters.Contains("@DE_ContractNR")) command.Parameters.Remove("@DE_ContractNR");
                if (command.Parameters.Contains("@DE_Price")) command.Parameters.Remove("@DE_Price");

                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_ItemNR", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500)) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_ItemNR"].Value = ptd.NAME_INFO.SALES_ITEM_INFORMATION.PRODUCT_SERVICE_ID;
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_ItemNDCNR", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500)) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_ItemNDCNR"].Value = ptd.NAME_INFO.SALES_ITEM_INFORMATION.PRODUCT_SERVICE_ID;
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_ProductUOM", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500)) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_ProductUOM"].Value = ptd.NAME_INFO.SALES_ITEM_INFORMATION.UNIT_OR_BASIS_FOR_MEASUREMENT_CODE;
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_CustomerAccountNR", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500)) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_CustomerAccountNR"].Value = ptd.NAME_INFO.IDENTIFICATION_CODE;
                if (ptd.NAME_INFO.IDENTIFICATION_CODE_QUALIFIER.Equals("11")){
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_CustomerDEANR", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500)) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_CustomerDEANR"].Value = ptd.NAME_INFO.IDENTIFICATION_CODE;
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_CustomerNPINR", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500)) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_CustomerNPINR"].Value = "-";
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_CustomerHINNR", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500)) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_CustomerHINNR"].Value = "-";
                }else if (ptd.NAME_INFO.IDENTIFICATION_CODE_QUALIFIER.Equals("21")){
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_CustomerDEANR", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500)) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_CustomerDEANR"].Value = "-";
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_CustomerNPINR", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500)) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_CustomerNPINR"].Value = "-";
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_CustomerHINNR", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500)) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_CustomerHINNR"].Value = ptd.NAME_INFO.IDENTIFICATION_CODE;
                }
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DE_CustomerName", SqlDbType.NVarChar ).Value=ptd.NAME_INFO.NAME;
                foreach (PRODUCT_TRANSFER_AND_RESALE_REPORTINTERCHANGEFUNCTIONAL_GROUPTRANSACTIONPTDNAME_INFOADDRESS_INFO add in ptd.NAME_INFO.ADDRESS_INFO){
                    if (command.Parameters.Contains("@DE_CustomerAddress1")) command.Parameters.Remove("@DE_CustomerAddress1");
                    if (command.Parameters.Contains("@DE_CustomerAddress2")) command.Parameters.Remove("@DE_CustomerAddress2");
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_CustomerAddress1", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500)) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_CustomerAddress1"].Value = add.ADDRESS_INFORMATION_1;
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_CustomerAddress2", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500)) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_CustomerAddress2"].Value = add.ADDRESS_INFORMATION_2;
                }
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_CustomerCity", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500)) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_CustomerCity"].Value = ptd.NAME_INFO.GEOGRAPHIC_LOCATION.CITY_NAME;
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_CustomerState", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500)) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_CustomerState"].Value = ptd.NAME_INFO.GEOGRAPHIC_LOCATION.STATE_OR_PROVINCE_CODE;
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_CustomerZipcode", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500)) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_CustomerZipcode"].Value = ptd.NAME_INFO.GEOGRAPHIC_LOCATION.POSTAL_CODE;
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_CustomerCountry", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500)) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_CustomerCountry"].Value = ptd.NAME_INFO.GEOGRAPHIC_LOCATION.COUNTRY_CODE;
                foreach (PRODUCT_TRANSFER_AND_RESALE_REPORTINTERCHANGEFUNCTIONAL_GROUPTRANSACTIONPTDNAME_INFOSALES_ITEM_INFORMATIONREF_ID refid in ptd.NAME_INFO.SALES_ITEM_INFORMATION.REF_ID ){
                    if (refid.REFERENCE_IDENTIFICATION_QUALIFIER.Contains("DI")){
                        if (command.Parameters.Contains("@DE_InvoiceNR")) command.Parameters.Remove("@DE_InvoiceNR");
                        if (command.Parameters.Contains("@DE_Invoicedate")) command.Parameters.Remove("@DE_Invoicedate");
                        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_InvoiceNR", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500)) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_InvoiceNR"].Value = refid.REFERENCE_IDENTIFICATION;
                        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_Invoicedate", SqlDbType.DateTime)) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_Invoicedate"].Value = refid.DATE;
                    }
                }

                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_QuantitySold", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18)) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_QuantitySold"].Value = ptd.NAME_INFO.SALES_ITEM_INFORMATION.QUANTITY;
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_QuantityReturned", SqlDbType.Decimal,18)) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_QuantityReturned"].Value = ptd.NAME_INFO.SALES_ITEM_INFORMATION.QUANTITY;
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_SalesReturnCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500)) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_SalesReturnCode"].Value = "-";
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_ContractNR", SqlDbType.NVarChar,500)) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_ContractNR"].Value = ptd.NAME_INFO.SALES_ITEM_INFORMATION.PRODUCT_SERVICE_ID;
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DE_Price", SqlDbType.Decimal,18)) ;
        command.Parameters["@DE_Price"].Value = ptd.NAME_INFO.SALES_ITEM_INFORMATION.MONETARY_AMOUNT;

        for (int i = 0; i < command.Parameters.Count; i++)
                {

                    if (command.Parameters[i].SqlDbType == SqlDbType.NVarChar) command.Parameters[i].Size = 500;
                    if (command.Parameters[i].SqlDbType == SqlDbType.Decimal)
                    {
                        command.Parameters[i].Size = 18;
                        command.Parameters[i].Scale = 6;
                    }
                    if (!SALESDATAQRY.Contains(command.Parameters[i].ParameterName)) logger.Error("Parameter not found: " + command.Parameters[i].ParameterName);
                    logger.Info(command.Parameters[i].ParameterName + ": " + command.Parameters[i].SqlDbType + " " + command.Parameters[i].Size + " " + command.Parameters[i].Scale + " " + command.Parameters[i].Value);

                }
                command.Prepare();

                logger.Info("inserted " + command.ExecuteNonQuery()+ " rows");       
            }
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SqlCommand.Prepare method requires all parameters to have an explicitly set type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938985/sqlcommand-prepare-method-requires-all-parameters-to-have-an-explicitly-set-type)

Comment: I checked that one too, but I'm already giving the explicit type and it's still not working...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this syntax:

```
var parameter = new SqlParameter("@InterchangeReceiverID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 500);
parameter.Value = "VALUEGOESHERE";

command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, you can use `AddWithValue` which implicitly cast the data type ofr you,

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InterchangeReceiverID", "VALUEGOESHERE");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `command.CreateParameter()` instead of instatiating `SqlParameter`.