# When executing command.Prepare() I have "SqlCommand.Prepare method requires all parameters to have an explicitly set type" error

Tags: stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I have the following statements:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataBaseName"]);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = "update Table1 set data = @data where id = @id";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =  data;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value =  id;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

try
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    con.Open();
    cmd.Prepare();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    return true;
}
```

When executing `cmd.Prepare()` I have an error `SqlCommand.Prepare method requires all parameters to have an explicitly set type`

I read some answers here, but looks like I did as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938985/sqlcommand-prepare-method-requires-all-parameters-to-have-an-explicitly-set-type)
but still have the same problem.

What am I missing?

Comment: `AddWithValue` does not add with type. It uses the second parameter as a value. You now have two untyped parameters whose values are integers equal to the enum members `SqlDbType.VarChar` and `SqlDbType.Int`. Also you might enjoy reading http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: Apparently @marc_s made a typo. Replace `AddWithValue` with `Add` and provide length for your varchar.

Comment: What should I do in the case if parameter is a `SqlDbType.DateTime` or `Int`?

Comment: Then don't provide length.